# How to stop task e-mail notification for SharePoint 2013 Designer Worfklow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

How do I stop a SharePoint 2013 workflow task from sending a notification to the task assignee. When a task is created it, sends an automatic notification to the task assignee. Can we stop the notification?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it sends e-mail to person who assigned task. Or do you mean that the person who got task assigned *should not* receive email notification at all?

Comment: I mean task is assigned only. no need to send notification to anyone.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any options in SharePoint Designer when assigning task to a user but there's a setting on the task list that can be changed.

If you go to task list settings -> Advanced settings, you should have "E-mail notification" setting. Check if your list has this part set to Yes, then change and test if that works for you.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe the below is what you're looking for.

1. Right-click the task action in SPD
2. Go to 'Properties'
3. Set 'WaiveAssignmentEmail' to 'Yes'

[image: WaiveAssignmentEmail]

That should do it - cheers!

Comment: This stops the workflow from sending any Task emails at all ... I just want it to send one email instead of 2.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the following steps.

1. GoTo SharePoint Designer
2. Open your Approval Process/Approval workflow
3. Click on Change the behavior of single task (Under Customization section)

[image]

4. Find for "**Email task notification to Workflow Context:Initiator**"
   (You can delete these kind of Email Actions from all the stages i.e when task expires, deleted, completes etc..)

[image]

5. Delete this step
6. Save --> Check for Errors
7. Publish the workflow.

Above steps will help you out. Please try and let me know.

Comment: This solution is working on SharePoint workflow 2010 but I am looking for SharePoint Workflow 2013.

Comment: @MohitSikhwal Yes you are right. This solution is for SP Workflow 2010. Sorry for the confusion.....